# How to traverse the following dict in python

Tags: python

I have a dict in which each index has array as value. I would like to retrieve each array and print each value in that array along with the index. How do I do it?

```
{'bridge0': [snic(family=18, address='3a:c9:86:61:01:00', netmask=None, broadcast=None, ptp=None)], 
'lo0': [snic(family=2, address='127.0.0.1', netmask='255.0.0.0', broadcast=None, ptp=None), snic(family=30, address='::1', netmask='ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff', broadcast=None, ptp=None), snic(family=30, address='fe80::1%lo0', netmask='ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::', broadcast=None, ptp=None)],
'en0': [snic(family=18, address='38:c9:86:16:8c:c9', netmask=None, broadcast=None, ptp=None)],
'en1': [snic(family=2, address='192.168.1.37', netmask='255.255.255.0', broadcast='192.168.1.255', ptp=None), snic(family=18, address='38:c9:86:3a:2a:7a', netmask=None, broadcast=None, ptp=None), snic(family=30, address='fe80::3acd:86ff:feea:2a7a%en1', netmask='ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::', broadcast=None, ptp=None)],
'en2': [snic(family=18, address='d2:00:1d:98:9b:d0', netmask=None, broadcast=None, ptp=None)],
'p2p0': [snic(family=18, address='1a:c9:86:ea:2a:7b', netmask=None, broadcast=None, ptp=None)],
'awdl0': [snic(family=18, address='66:f7:08:8a:1f:d3', netmask=None, broadcast=None, ptp=None), snic(family=30, address='fe80::64f7:8ff:fe8a:1fc3%awdl0', netmask='ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::', broadcast=None, ptp=None)],
'vboxnet0': [snic(family=2, address='192.168.99.1', netmask=None, broadcast='192.168.99.255', ptp=None), snic(family=18, address='0a:00:27:00:00:10', netmask=None, broadcast=None, ptp=None)],
'fw0': [snic(family=18, address='08:74:02:ff:fe:d9:89:bx', netmask=None, broadcast=None, ptp=None)]}<br>
```

This is what I have tried.Where `netw` is the dict above :

```
 for x,y in netw:
       print x
       print y
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley here is the tried code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate over a dictionary in Python, you'll get its keys. If you want both the keys and the values, iterate over the `items()` of the dictionary:

```
for key, value in netw.items():
    # maybe iterate again over the value list here?
    print  key, value
```

On Python 2, if your dictionary has many values, you may want to use `iteritems()` instead of `items()` (the former returns an iterator, rather than putting all the items in a list). In Python 3, `items()` returns a "view" object, which is a lightweight iterable not too much different from the iterator returned by `iteritems` in Python 2.